# How to change the header background of a GroupBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I change the `Background` of the header of a `GroupBox`?
I'm trying to do that with:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="0">
   <GroupBox.Header>
       <Setter Property="Background" //<- no backgroundproperty
```

there is no `Background` property

Comment: WPF controls don't have a single appearance, so the look of a `GroupBox` may change depending on the style applied, which may be a custom style or the default style for the current system theme.  Some styles may define a custom background for the header.  If you want to _ensure_ the look of a `GroupBox` in any environment, you may need to define a custom template.

Comment: @mm8 I upvoted your answer, but you need to calm down, I preferred to assign the accepted answer to a user who has much less reputation than you, it is not a personal fact I hope you understand, have a good day :)

Comment: @ilsantino: Now you have an upvote:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `Border` in the `Header` and set the Background of it to your desired color:

```
<GroupBox >
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Border Background="Red">
            <Label Content="Hello"></Label>
        </Border>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: No difference, I just saw your answer after posting my answer. I was less than 2 minutes later. You got an upvote from me for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `Header` property to any UI element including a `Grid` or a `Border` for example:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Border Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="header..." />
        </Border>
    </GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="content..."></TextBlock>
</GroupBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site: [Control Templates, Styles, and Triggers](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2011/06/16/control-templates-styles-and-triggers-in-wpf.aspx)

this is probably more than you need, but it explains how to use a control template to modify controls in various ways. I use this particular control (with different colors) for groupboxes on one of my applications, and it has come in very handy.